# RewriteCond: redirecting all request from specific domains

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a RewriteCond that will redirect a number of domains to a given URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain1.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain2.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://www.google.com/ [L]
```

This is almost working fine. When visiting my domain, I'm redirected to *google.com*. But when visiting *domain1.com/a-sub-folder*, it does not match my *RewriteCond*.

What could I add to the *RewriteCond* to make them match the above URL?

**EDIT1:**
Also, is it possible to add some HTTP 301 response to the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^(/)?$` in the rewrite rule match only an empty path, I replaced it with `.*`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain1.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain2.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you. What about the OR flag in the first Cond, is that ok? Should I add other flags as well?

Comment: that's ok,it should work, you can add `NC` flag to ignore case however (replace `[OR]` with `[OR,NC]`)

Comment: And the last Cond chould have only [NC]?